# C# How to change the color of a button for one second

Tags: c#

Is there a way without a timer to change to color of a button for one second?
I have:
btnRed.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
So far but I only want that changed for a second.

Comment: How do you expect to do it without a timer? And why not a timer? This really makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an asynchronous method like this:

```
private async Task ChangeColor(Color new_color)
{
    var original_color = btnRed.BackColor;

    btnRed.BackColor = new_color;

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    btnRed.BackColor = original_color;
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
ChangeColor(Color.DarkRed);
```

Comment: Only problem with that is that it will block the main thread for 1 second. If that's not a problem, then this is fine, but if you want the app to remain responsive, you'll need another way.

Comment: @ColinGrealy, why do you think it will block the main thread?

Comment: apologies, I didn't read your code correctly. You're right ; it won't block.

Comment: Not a  strictly C# programmer, but just of curiosity - what would have to change in the code to actually block the main thread?

Comment: @CreativeMagic, simply use a normal method instead of an asynchronous method, and then replace `await Task.Delay` with `Thread.Sleep`.